# How to Rewrite e custom post type slug for multiple type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I've using custom post type UI Plugin and creating three  type posts. 1.Services 2.Location and 3. our Team when I using below code its working only single type not multiple .

```
function overwrite_gallery_slug( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type === 'services') {

            $args['rewrite'] = array (
                'slug'       => 'specialties',
                'with_front' => false,
            );
    }

   if( $post_type === 'location') {

            $args['rewrite'] = array (
                'slug'       => '/about-us/locations',
                'with_front' => false,
            );
    }
 
   if ( 'team' === $post_type ) {
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] ='visitor/teams';
    } 

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'overwrite_gallery_slug', 10, 2 );
```

I've trired wp code but its not working for multiples.

Comment: I have tried your code and it's working fine for multiple post types.

Comment: code are working fine when I visit my URL after code it will true only one condition.

Comment: It is working fine for all custom post types. All conditions are accepted.